# How to set image src from variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

i have following issue:

Calling and rendering an external image url from an api endpoint and setting this as an varibale.

The variable is then placed within in the view as `<img src=<%= @image %>>` but for some reason it gets attached to the active pages url instead of handling it as an external url.

So the image is shown as 'broken' because the url looks then like this `http://active.url.com/blog/http://image.url.com/image.jpg`

Doing the same with plain text i.e. `<img src="http://image.url.com/image.jpg>` renders the image as desired.

Any ideas?

Comment: What value does `@image` have?

Comment: It has the full url to the image e.g. `http://image.url.com/image.jpg`

Comment: Does this make any difference? `<img src="<%= @image %>">`

Comment: No already tried..it still ataches the external url to the url of the view and breaks

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it has the full url? Have you tried printing out `@image` in your view, with `<p><%= @image.inspect %></p>` or something like that?

Comment: Ok i got it know. For some reason it ignored the https:// prefix so i had to attach it to the variable manually as it wasnt part of the API response. Now it works as expected! Shame on me! Thanks anyway guys!